# Could I take a variation of a functional in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, variational-calculus

In finite element, the weak form can be derived by taking the variation of a energy functional as:

\begin{align}
    L(u(x,y)) &= -\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}(\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}})d\Omega+\int_{\Omega}fud\Omega\\
\delta{}L(u(x,y))&=-\int_{\Omega}(\dfrac{\partial{\delta{}u}}{\partial{x}}\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\dfrac{\partial{\delta{}u}}{\partial{y}}\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}})d\Omega+\int_{\Omega}f\delta{}ud\Omega=0
\end{align}

How could I do such type of derivation in Mathematica. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have a specific u(x,y) that you are trying to find L and deltaL for?